# Does dialogflow learn from user data

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

Does dialogflow learn from user data? For example, I built a chatbot which answers some general-purpose queries. Whatever questions a user asks(relevant or irrelevant), does dialogflow uses that to train the agent?

Please let me know if the question is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

DialogFlow has done a very basic NLP for you. What I mean by that is that if a user enters something very similar to what you have added in `User Says` section the specified Intent will be triggered. But it does not learn on its own. You will have to see the user queries from the training tab and add these queries by yourself in order for it to work.

Comment: I see. A snippet from one of my datasets is following:

"courses":[
    {
  "courseNumber":"CPSC 103",
  "courseName":"Introduction to Personal Computer Applications",
  "units":"3",
  "description":"",
  "prerequisite":"",
  "level":"undergrad"
 },

The user query is: "Prerequisite for CPSC 103". Now even if the user says, CS 103 or computer science 103, I would like the bot to give the same response. One way is write multiple 'User Says', but can it be achieved by writing my own NLP?

Comment: Please ignore my poor formatting. Quite new to stack overflow and unable to edit my comment now.

Comment: One way to recognize variables in what user says is by using `Entities`. Here you can add different type of ways in which a user can frame a question and map a variable for that set.
For eg: you can have an entity for `CS: [CS 103, computer science 103]`, you can use this like @sys.CS. Please read about https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities and you will find your solution

Answer (score 1):

See, there is basic difference between AI & ML, understanding & interpreting the context of what user wants to say & then performing tasks is AI, on the contrary, ML involves when you try to learn something from user responses & then try to answer. NLP here tries to match user-entered response to user says in dialogflow.com & then compute the score, based on which our bot pick up an intent & answer the user. That's it! In case of dialogflow.com, it will never be like it has stored 1000 user responses & then it has used it for learning & answering. So the answer to user question is No!

Now coming to second point, if you'd like to explicitly train a bot based on specific responses, there's provision to do so. You can move to Training tab & then choose a dialog where you can check matched & unmatched intents. You can choose to right intent & say approve to train your bot. Please check snaps for more understanding.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can train the agent using the training tab & discard the irrelevant user queries. Is that what you were looking for?